# Timeout issues of webparts in SharePoint 2019 on-premise

Tags: 2019, custom-web-parts

Our SharePoint sites were migrated from 2013 to 2019 on-premise. Since the migration done a week ago, we’ve been having issues with our custom webparts on all the pages throughout a site, where users with viewing access receive the following error.

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

```
Correlation ID:4291e8a0-77eb-a07e-a7cb-7ba2b5f3863e
```

The temporary way to fix the site pages is for me - with site collection access privileges - to refresh one page with a webpart, which seems to fix the issue for the rest of the pages for my viewers. They are then able to see what they are supposed to see. The issue continues coming back. I have checked the ULS Logs and the error produces the following:

> Exception while getting CustomXsl: System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
> (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException
> ex, Boolean allowCompleteRequest)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsStream(String bstrUrl,
> StorePath bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel,
> OpenBinaryFlags grfob, String bstrEtagNotMatch, Object punkSPFileMgr,
> Boolean bHonorCustomIrm, IrmProtectionParams fileIrmSettings, UInt32&
> pdwVirusCheckStatus, Int32& plVirusVendorId, String&
> pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagNew, String& pContentTagNew,
> SPFileInfo& pFileProps, Guid& pgWebIdReal, Guid& pgDoclibId)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.GetFileStream(SPWeb web, SPResourcePath
> fileUrl, SPFileLevel level, OpenBinaryFlags openOptions, String
> etagNotMatch, ISPFileStreamManager spMgr,
> SPFileRightsManagementSettings rightsManagementSettings, Boolean
> throwOnVirusFound, SPVirusCheckStatus& virusCheckStatus, Int32&
> virusVendorId, String& virusCheckMessage, String& etagNew, String&
> contentTagNew, SPFileInfo& fileprops, Guid& doclibId, Guid&
> webIdForAuditing)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.OpenBinaryStream(SPOpenBinaryOptions
> openOptions, String etagNotMatch, String& etagNew, String&
> contentTagNew)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.CmsDataFormWebPart.GetXslContents(String
> url)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.CmsDataFormWebPart.GetKnownXsl()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.get_CustomizedXsl()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver
> someXmlResolver)

I've checked to make sure that the [Style Resource Readers] group has access to the Style Library it has.  This was recommended to check as per a question posted here:
[Access denied for xsl files in style library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293822/access-denied-for-xsl-files-in-style-library).

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?